# SwiftRealm optional value with default

Tags: swift, macos, realm

I am very new to Realm but I was wondering if there was a way to set the default of an optional value to another variable. I know this sounds very confusing but I hope my code will explain it. My goal is to create Directories with multiple categories. If the user does not enter a custom for the category, it will default to the last path component (folder name). Does anyone have any ideas about how to do this? I was thinking about doing `@objc dynamic var name: String = (path as NSString).lastPathComponent` but it wouldn't work. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

```
    class Category: Object {
    let name = (LinkingObjects(fromType: Category.self, property: "path") as NSString).lastPathComponent
    @objc dynamic var path = ""
    @objc dynamic var directory: Directory?
}


class Directory: Object {
    @objc dynamic var name = ""
    @objc dynamic var path = ""
    let categories = List<Category>()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a `Realm` issue, but a Swift issue in general. You cannot declare an instance property and assign it a value in which you are referring to the value of another instance property, since instance properties are only guaranteed to have a value at the end of the initializer, but when you declare an instance property with a default value, that gets called before the initializer, so there's no guarantee that the other properties already have values.

If you need `name` to be a persisted Realm property, you won't be able to use your other instance property to get a default value, however, if you don't need to persist `name` in `Realm`, you can simply make `name` a `lazy` variable and hence you'll be able to access other instance properties.

```
lazy var name = (path as NSString).lastPathComponent
```

Comment: So if my `Categories` Class had the variables name: `lazy var name = (path as NSString).lastPathComponent`, path: `@objc dynamic var path = “”`, and directory: `@objc dynamic var directory: Directory?`, would the user be able to add their own value? Or would `lazy var name: String = ((path as NSString).lastPathComponent)?` make the value of `name` equal to the file name optional?

Comment: I looked into it a little more and I think I found the answer. I think I'll be able to add my own value to `name` if I use either `lazy var name: String = (path as NSString).lastPathComponent` or `lazy var name: String? = (path as NSString).lastPathComponent`, but I'm not sure which one.

Comment: @AndrewWiggin yes, the value of `name` can be changed, it's just the initial value that automatically gets  assigned based on the `path` instance property. You don't actually need the type annotation, but if you really want to add it, you can simply check the actual type by alt+clicking on the variable, but it will be of type `String`.